# Error when COUNT after MAX?

Tags: sql, mysql, count

I have a table Act in a medical database :

```
IDAct   Historic      IDPatient
1       2001-01-01    1
1       2001-01-02    1
2       2001-01-01    2
3       2001-01-03    1
```

I would like to compute the column IDActPerPatient:

```
IDAct   Historic      IDPatient  IDActPerPatient
1       2001-01-02    1          1
2       2001-01-01    2          1
3       2001-01-03    1          2
```

The Act table contains Acts with the historic of every modification of an act. (the index is the pair (IDAct,Historic)).
So I'm interested in the last modified acts:

```
SELECT A.IDActe, MAX(Historic) AS Historic FROM Act A GROUP BY IDAct
```

Now, I'd like to number the Acts per patient. So I count the number of acts with an IDAct less or equal for one patient.
I have created a view LastAct with the previous request and I try this one :

```
SELECT DA1.*, COUNT(*) AS IDActPerPatient
FROM LastAct DA1
INNER JOIN LastAct DA2 ON DA1.IDPatient = DA2.IDPatient 
AND DA2.IDActe >= DA1.IDAct
GROUP BY DA1.IDAct
```

...which does not work!
I get large numbers in IDActPerPatient when an act has several version in historic (for a patient who has 1 act in 3 versions I have 81).

Do you have an idea where the problem comes from ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.IDActe,
       MAX(Historic) AS Historic,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IDAct) FROM ACT B WHERE A.IDPatient=B.IDPatient)
FROM Act A
GROUP BY IDAct
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I don't use select in the select enough but It's really helpful here!
here is the fixed request:

```
SELECT A.IDAct, A.IDPatient, 
       MAX(Historic) AS Historic, 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IDAct) FROM Act B WHERE A.IDPatient=B.IDPatient 
        AND A.IDAct>=B.IDAct) AS IDActPerPatient
FROM Act A
GROUP BY IDAct
```